# Cart shortcode is not working in cart66 WordPress plugin

Tags: plugins

I have installed cart66 plugin in my WordPress site and created one demo cart66 post. 
When I click on the 'add to cart' button I get redirected to the cart page, which is blank.
So I guess the problem is with the 'cart' shortcode.

Does anyone have any idea about what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
[cart]

my page that works is:

<h1>Your Shopping Cart</h1>
[cart]
```